# informatica uncached lookup on target

Tags: lookup, informatica

Here is my problem:

- I need to implement an uncached lookup in a mapping.
- This lookup is    connected and must return multiple value.
- This lookup is overrided    with ISNULL for null value and condition
  to limit the selection.
- This    lookup search in a target table.

The problem is, everything work except the uncached part : when i insert a line in the target, this line is not taken into account and the lookup do like if no insertion were done.

I put commit to '1' and commit type to 'source' since i need to refresh the lookup for each source line. (maybe there is a way to refresh on each insertion in the target table but i didn't found it)

Does someone already faced this case and is there a solution ?
It's like if the uncached option doesn't work ???

I my algorithm :

- If the lookup find no match, it must insert.
- If the lookup find a match, it must not insert (nor udpate).
- When i insert a line it must not be inserted twice if there is multiple occurence in the same execution (i cannot filter duplicate cause i use it elsewhere and cannot do primary key reject for other reasons).

Thanks for any solution !

Comment: You can probably use dynamic lookup, instead of an uncached lookup.

Comment: Dynamic lookup option is greyed in my case...

Comment: "_i cannot filter duplicate cause i use it elsewhere_" - you can filter duplicates in one branch of your mapping without affecting other targets.

Comment: My bad, you cannot use dynamic cache in case of active lookup returning multiple rows.

Comment: No problem, i built a workaround with a sorter and an expression to check if key is to insert, give it an id, then give all duplicate lines to insert with the same key the same id and only insert the first line. It's dirty but business will be happy... If i found a better solution before the end of the projet i will implement it.

Comment: @DevJoe13 I am working on a similar problem, and taking a similar approach to that described in your comment. Can you elaborate on your solution in an answer if it succeeds?